# Reinstall file from RPM?

Tags: yum, rpm

So I need to install the original /etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac file from the authconfig RPM. I attempted to do so by "reinstalling" the authconfig package/rpm like so:

```
mv /etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac ~/
rpm -e --justdb --nodeps authconfig
yum install authconfig
```

The files are not re-installed though. What needs to be done to get yum to reinstall the files?

**UPDATE:**

Did an strace on the yum install and it appears that the file "/etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac" is opened by the rpm install but not written to. Looking further it appears that the file is generated once the authconfig binary is executed.

So now the problem is no longer RPM related. I need to figure out what the default command to authconfig looks like for RH5.6 so I can get a normal system-auth-ac file.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
yum -y install yum-utils
yumdownloader authconfig
rpm -Uvh --replacepkgs authconfig*
```

EDIT:

Try this:

```
system-config-authentication
```

Comment: While the commands exit without error the files still do not exist within /etc/pam.d

Comment: sorry, that last command has been updated above, please try it again.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out on my own and added the U. Unfortunately, while this RPM "owns" the system-auth-ac file I am trying to install..it doesn't actually copy it into place on RPM install. The file is generated using the authconfig binary. Only god knows what the default authconfig arguments are for RH though. :(